# @Transactional not working with SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, transactional

I'm trying to create Java application and cannot make @Transactional annotation work.

I have example PaymentDao class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional; 

@Repository
public class PaymentDao {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public PaymentDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Transactional
public void add(Payment payment) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .save(payment);
        if (payment != null) throw new RuntimeException();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .save(payment);

        }
}
```

And despite RuntimeException is thrown, first object is always saved into database.
I noticed that when I try to do it that way:

```
public void add(Payment payment) {
    try {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().begin();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .save(payment);
        if (payment != null) throw new RuntimeException();
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .save(payment);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
    } catch(RuntimeException e) {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    } 
}
```

it works and no entity is saved.

Shouldn't @Transactional annotation work the same? What have I missed?
Here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Config {

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(HibernateEntityManagerFactory 
hemf){
     return hemf.getSessionFactory();
     }
}
```

EDIT:
I'm calling it from Service:

```
@Service
public class PaymentService {

@Autowired
private PaymentDao paymentDao;

public void add(PaymentDto paymentDto) throws IOException {
    Payment payment = paymentDto.toEntity();
    paymentDao.add(payment);
}
}
```

which is autowired into controller.

hibernate configuration is simple:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testT
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin1
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor
=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class
=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE
```

Comment: On a completely separate note, DAO logic of the variety you're writing can be autogenerated for you by Spring Data.

Comment: yeah, I know, but I'm just learning right now and try to get to know also other ways either.

Comment: @Besanouno Where are you calling the add method from?

Comment: Show your hibernate configuration (also you are using JPA why are you switching back to plain hibernate?).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `TransactionManager` and associate `SessionFactory` or `DataSource` that `SessionFactory` is using to that `TransactionManager`.